# JestJS can't instantiate new EventEmmiter in spec files

Tags: reactjs, testing, typeerror, jestjs, eventemitter

Whenever I try to test a component which is using `eventemitter2` and tries to make a new instance of it so for example `import EventEmitter from 'eventemitter2'` and then `new EventEmitter()` in my spec files, it throws an error `TypeError: _eventemitter2.default is not a constructor.`
Any ideas what could cause this issue? Thank you.

update: It happens also in Jasmine and Mocha

Comment: shouldn't it be `import {EventEmitter2} from 'eventemitter2'`?

Comment: Actually you are right, it works this way-thank you, but on the other hand `import EventEmitter from 'eventemitter2` works in clean npm project. is it possible it's somehow connected of how babel transorms ES6 Modules to CommonJS?